Spring Cloud Gateway - Circuit Breaker - in AWS AutoScale Group
I have a Spring Cloud Gateway, that has a circuit breaker (Resilience 4j)
However, to accommodate for load, I am thinking of putting it in a Amazon Web Services, Auto Scaling Group, so depending on traffic, multiple instances get spun up.
This is fine for the

Token Relay Gateway (as state is stored in Redis)
Time Out Limiter (as this is per request)
Retry Mechanism (as this is per request)
Rate Limiter (as the state per key, is stored in Redis)
Circuit Breaker, right now the state is stored in memory, so if I have multiple instances of this server then each will have its own Circuit Breaker State, and so will give inconsistent behaviour.

Any workarounds or alternative solutions to this? Should I even bother with a Circuit Breaker in Spring, or is that something I should consider putting in AWS Lambda, or AWS API Gateway, if supported?
